# VBA changes Excel 2002 -> Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, migration

Where can I find a *complete* list of changes in VBA from Excel XP (2002) to Excel 2007?  I have a workbook that relies heavily on VBA which I have been working on in 2002, and when I opened it in 2007, I noticed that some things had changed.  For instance, my workbook does lots of 3d rotation; I discovered that `Shape.ThreeD.RotationX` has become `Shape.ThreeD.RotationY` and vice-versa.  I also discovered that I have to negate the rotation values, so that

```
Shape.ThreeD.RotationX = 90
```

becomes

```
Shape.ThreeD.RotationY = -90
```

I am sure that there are other changes as well, which I have probably missed.  I haven't seen the above changes detailed anywhere, so I would like to know:

Which sites detail changes such as the ones I have outline above?

Comment: If someone would have published a 'complete' list of what VBA in Excel XP did in the first place,. We could compare and contrast to the other incomplete lists of VBA in Excel 2007.

Comment: Afraid I don't know the answer to your question, but in my limited experience, Excel VBA functionality is VERY patchy in 2007 compared to previous versions. Some stuff you just can't do, even if you record a macro and replay it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Excel 2007 and go into the VBA editor (Alt+F11)
2. Open up **Help** (F1)
3. Click **What's New**
4. Click **Object Model Changes Since Microsoft Office XP (2002)**

Voila!

This list is fairly comprehensive as well as interactive, so I won't reproduce it here. But it also has changes since the 97, 2000, and 2003 versions.

Comment: I have seen that list on MSDN, but it isn't complete.  It doesn't list the changes that are outlined in the question, so I can't be sure that it lists all other changes either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the changes that I have noticed so far:

```
Shape.ThreeD.RotationX = 90
```

has become

```
Shape.ThreeD.RotationY = -90
```

(i.e. X and Y axis have been swapped around for 3d rotation on autoshapes, and the positive / negative directions along these axis are the opposite way round).

Excel no longer seems to honour the

```
Shape.ThreeD.ExtrusionColorType = msoExtrusionColorAutomatic
```

directive (it just gives a black extrusion, at least on my tests).

ThreeD shapes must now have their lighting direction set explicitly, e.g.

```
Shape.ThreeD.PresetLightingDirection = msoLightingRight
```

whereas previously this didn't seem to be necessary.

These are just some of the things that I have discovered so far.  I am sure that there are many more - I will add them as I find them (I will try to put things relating to auto-shapes in this answer, and group other changes / problems in separate answers to make it easier to browse).

If you have code that makes use of

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

to speed itself up, you have to explicitly call

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

before showing a MsgBox or InputBox if you want changes to display on screen (whereas 2002 would *always* refresh the screen before showing any dialog box).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can try to make changes based on an incomplete "Exhaustive" list, but you still have to test the code and see what doesn't work the way you expect. After making changes so it works in 2007, you also need to test in the original version, so it still works for those users.